# .htaccess rewrite for user profile page does not work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with Htacces file , the thing is I am trying to do a Profile URL 
ex : www.mysite.com/profilename --> this link will take me to the user profile and its working because of

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
```

no the thing is whenever I try to access any other directory for example www.mysite.com/login it changes the url to www.mysite.com/login/u?=login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on if `login` is an actual file or directory rather than another script needing another htaccess rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This checks first to see if the directory or file exists before executing your `RewriteRule` directive.